# Different colors and Metamerism

Tags: color

How can I draw graphs (metamers) without calculating any functions?

For example, for the (each) following cones (imaginary):
[image]

Update:

Each graph describe a cone of animal (imaginary) and showing the
response to the spectrum of colors.

I want to draw two graphs (metamerism) to these responses.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question isn't clear at all. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear on the question. What do functions have to do with picking colors?

Comment: So basically you want to draw the graphs pictured above in an image editing program? What does color (the tag) have to do with the question and what software do you plan on creating this with or what software do you have available?

Comment: OK, I want to draw for each graph  (=  response of cone  to the spectrum of colors)  additional equivalent graph (=metamer) that showing   response to the spectrum  of  colors (but is different).  for example : http://i.stack.imgur.com/AqkEH.jpg

Comment: @ AndrewH: No, without  image editing program (simple graph (with a pencil)).

Comment: @user I am still having trouble understanding your question. I understand that this is for the color spectrum, but what is the end result you're trying to achieve? Are you having trouble creating a legend for the graph? Are you having trouble incorporating colors into the graph? What part of this question has to do with graphic design? The terms you're using are just going over my head.

Comment: Is it possible to describe two different graphs (as in the example) that represent essentially the same color ? If yes, so how?

Comment: I don't know what cones and metamers are. Can you define those for us?

Comment: [metamerism] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamerism_%28color%29)

Comment: [cones ] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_cell )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off your last question:

> Describe two different graphs (as in the example) that represent
>   essentially the same color

I think the graphs themselves show the necessary data to come to the conclusion that these 2 separate animals share the ability to see parts of the color spectrum wavelength.

**My suggestion would be to create a legend, use text to describe the graphs, or make a graph that shows both data points on the same graph**. See an example graph I made.

[image: Example graph with both data points]

A graph with the color spectrum wavelength behind the data points.

[image: Example graph with the color spectrum]

If you're doing this with pencil, I would suggest using color pencils or some type of pattern to distinguish the data points.

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly the same graph(s) and not "metamer".

Comment: I meant : ".. essentially the same color" but with different  wavelength .

Comment: @user I think I understand your question know after seeing a [metamer graph](http://imagebank.osa.org/getImage.xqy?img=cCF6ekAubGFyZ2Usam9zYWEtMjktMi1BMzY2LWcwMTA). I have no idea how you can translate the graph shown above into a metamer graph without using an equation or using some software to plot the points for you. I still don't see how this is a graphic design question. My only other suggestion is to create the graph online using some graph tool and entering in the data shown above to create a curved line graph.

Comment: How to by equation, ideas ?

Comment: This is associated with calculate the integral ?

Comment: @user I don't have an answer for that. You can try asking over at http://math.stackexchange.com/. Otherwise, you can find a graph tool online and just input the data points for a curved line graph. For your second comment, I have no idea... I have very little knowledge for what you're doing.